# ocLazyLoad: error using ngSanitizer

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I want to use the angular application ngSanitize to use plain HTML in my application. I basically want to reproduce the functionality explained [here in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) but I want to lazy-load the module with ocLazyLoad. But for some reason I still get the error `Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context` indicating that ngSanitize was not load properly.

Did I do something wrong or is this a bug?

Here a minified example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" ng-app="LazyLoadTest" ng-controller="TestController">
    <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module("LazyLoadTest", [ "oc.lazyLoad"])
            .controller("TestController", function($scope, $ocLazyLoad, $compile){
                $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: "ngSanitize",
                        files: ["angular-sanitize.js"],
                        serie: true
                    }).then(function () {
                        $scope.myHTML =
                            'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
                            '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
                    }, function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here without using lazy loading:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-sanitize.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" ng-app="LazyLoadTest" ng-controller="TestController">
    <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module("LazyLoadTest", [ "ngSanitize"])
            .controller("TestController", function($scope){
                $scope.myHTML =
                            'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
                            '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/176.

Apparently ngSanitizer is coupled too tightly into AngularJS to be lazy loaded.

**Edit:**

Note that this fact is now also mentioned in the [FAQ](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/faq).